# In R, Why my hierarchy clustering plot looks so strange?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

Here is my data:

```
Friendly<-c(0.533,0.854,0.9585,0.925,0.9125,0.9815,0.9645,0.981,0.9935,0.9585,0.996,0.956,0.9415)
Polite<-c(0,0.45,0.977,0.9915,0.929,0.981,0.9895,0.9875,1,0.96,0.996,0.873,0.9125)
Praising<-c(0,0,0.437,0.9585,0.9415,0.9605,0.998,0.998,0.8915,1,1,1,0.977)
Joking<-c(0,0,0,0.617,0.942,0.9665,0.9935,0.992,0.935,0.987,0.975,0.9915,0.9665)
Sincere<-c(0,0,0,0,0.617,0.8335,0.985,0.9895,0.977,0.9205,1,0.9585,0.8895)
Serious<-c(0,0,0,0,1,0.642,0.975,0.9605,0.9645,0.9895,0.8125,0.9605,0.925)
Hostile<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0.629,0.656,0.948,0.9705,0.9645,0.998,0.9685)
Rude<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.687,0.979,0.954,0.954,0.996,0.956)
Irony<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.354,0.9815,0.996,1,0.971)
Insincere<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0.396,0.996,0.9915,0.9415)
Commanding<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0.462,0.9605,0.9165)
Suggesting<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.867,0.775)
Neutral<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.283)

data <- data.frame(Friendly,Polite,Praising,Joking,Sincere,Serious,Hostile,Rude,Irony,Insincere,Commanding,Suggesting,Neutral)
```

Actually, it is a distance matrix. Using R, I can plot a clustering dendrogram with this matrix:

```
dist<-as.dist(data)
hc<-hclust(dist, method="ward.D")
plot(hc, main="", ylab="", sub="", ann=T, axes=T, hang=0.3)
```

`
The dendrogram looks like this:

[image]

However, no matter how I set the parameter after "hang=", it is still a dendrogram with some groups hanging on the sky or in the ground with very long branch. So, how to solve this problem? What I want to get is a dendrogram in which the names of labels are in the bottom and the branches are not so long and the crotches(nodes) are not all in the very top anymore. 
What I want is a plot like this, anyone could help me?
[image]

Comment: Hi Ping, could you please use the `dput` function to get us your data in a more easy to reproduce fashion? (p.s.: probably using as.dendrogram, and then plot, would help)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I do not know how to change data into a reproduce fashion using dput function, I tried, but it didn't work. I know the format of codes (using " ` " before and after codes with four spaces). It will be appreciate if you could tell me how to fix this problem. :)

Comment: ping, if your object is (say) x<-c(1:5,7).  You can then place it in dput(x), to get the R code needed to run in order to reproduce x. Please use that on your hclust object, and paste it in your question (and comment that you've done so)